# Reset a FormGroup to predefined state using Formgroup.reset()

Tags: angular

In my Angular 2 component I'm using a `Formgroup` with 18 `AbstractControl`s. Users can edit their profile, which is loaded from the database.
I want to add a `Reset`-button to reset the form to it's original state (obviously). Using `this.form.reset()` however clears all fields. I can reset a specific `AbstractControl` within the `FormGroup` by calling `reset({firstname: 'Jack'});`.
Is it possible to change the state of `FormGroup` it resets to?

Comment: Just reinitialize the entire form

Comment: That would be almost like using `reset` for each specific `AbstractControl` within the `FormGroup`. That's what I'm trying to avoid, because its ugly'. It seems to me that that's what `reset()` is for.

Comment: On form intiailization, you can declare the default value for each Formcontrol, just modify what that variable is.

Comment: I initialize the form using the following code: `this.profileForm = this.formBuilder.group({firstname: [this.profile.firstname, Validators.required]});`
Isn't that correct?

Comment: What are you initializing `profile.firstname` to, and what are you trying to reset the form to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you build (or have built) your form as such, that the `profile` object matches the properties in your form group, you can just call:

```ts
this.profileForm.reset(this.profile);
```

for example:

```ts
profile = {firstname: 'first name'};

// ...

this.profileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  firstname: [this.profile.firstname],
});

// ...

this.profileForm.reset(this.profile)
```

With template:

```html
<form [formGroup]="profileForm">
  <input formControlName="firstname" />
</form>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-exj6gl?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Very nice, it had to be something simple and straightforward. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome, glad to hear it fit your requirement. Have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a form initialize function, and call it after you reset

component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm">
  <input formControlName="firstname" class="form-control">

  <button class="btn" type="submit">Submit </button>
  <button class="btn" type="button" (click)="onReset()">Reset </button>
</form>
```

Component.ts

```
  profileForm: FormGroup;

  profile  = {
    firstname: 'name'
  }
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();

  }

  initForm() {

    this.profileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstname: [this.profile.firstname, Validators.required]
    });
  }
  onReset() {
    this.profileForm.reset();
    this.initForm();
  }
```